# Subclassing an AS3 Array: how to get array elements (this[0] does not work)?

Tags: arrays, apache-flex, actionscript-3

If I am a subclass of an Array, how do I access an element?

```
class ArrayOfFoo extends Array
{
   public function getFooAt(anIndex : int) : Foo
   {
        return this[anIndex] as Foo;   //  <---- looks for an object attribute (named "0", for example)
   }
}
```

I could wrap an array instead of subclassing it, however lacking a universal IArray interface, that is less than useful for standard and custom functions expecting an Array.

Vectors do not allow subclassing at all, so they won't help.

Thanks

Comment: If you're subclassing an Array, you need to set the class to `dynamic`.

Comment: First off, I assume since you're posting this question that your code snippet does not work.  Do you get an error?  What is the error?  Is it a compile time or run time error?  Is this Flex specific code?  If so, then you can create a collection that implements ICollectionView.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ICollectionView.html .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not as straight forward as you think. Check [Extending the Array class on Adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=10_Lists_of_data_7.html) for the detail method of extending an array.